# Python/NetCDF4: How to duplicate a NetCDF file?

Tags: python, netcdf

I would like to duplicate a NetCDF file before:

a) updating the values of a variable within the second file, and/or

b) adding a new variable to the second file which corresponds to the structure of a variable from the original.

I can do this sort of duplication already but my process is tedious and feels piecemeal, so I wonder if there's a more elegant, simpler solution. For example, I want the resulting NetCDF file to contain all the global attributes, coordinate dimensions, coordinate variables, and possibly data variables as the original NetCDF file.

I would then want to create another variable in the second NetCDF with the same dimensions as one of the variables of the original (this is already doable as well, but looking for a better way). Probably what I'm looking for is a way to perform the functionality of `nccopy` within a Python script. Such a function doesn't appear to be present in the `netcdf4` module, but perhaps there's another trick I can use for this?

Maybe this is as simple as just copying the original file and modifying the copy where appropriate? Or open the original NetCDF and use the [copy](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html) module to create the second NetCDF?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions or insight.

Comment: As I see it, the only advantage of `nccopy` is that you can change the NetCDF format (classic, 4, ..)? Is that necessary? If not, why not simply copy the file (using e.g. `shutil`)? As for changing the 2nd file; you mention that this is _doable_ but that you are looking for a better way. What is the _doable_ solution that you are currently using?

Comment: It's tedious and piecemeal -- basically copying all the dimensions, attributes, and variables over into the second file. I often manage to forget something and end up with files that are almost alike, and then when I need to do difference maps or something of the sort something inevitably isn't congruous and I need to backtrack to fix some small detail. This is the sort of annoyance I'm trying to minimize by taking another approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With [NCO](http://nco.sf.net) this would be something like

```
ncap2 -s 'new_var=old_var+20' in.nc out.nc
```

and you would use -v to control whether you want just new_var and old_var, or all the contents of in.nc to be in out.nc.

Answer (score 3):

I'll provide an [`xarray`](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/) solution to what you're trying to do. `xarray` has "round-trip" abilities that allow you to read/write the same netCDF file, so this could be a nice way to go.

```
import xarray as xr

# open your dataset
ds = xr.open_dataset('your_original_file.nc')

# change an existing variable
ds.your_var += 20

# add a new variable
ds['new_var'] = xr.DataArray([1, 2, 3, 4], dims=('new_dim', ))

# write to a new file
ds.to_netcdf('your_new_file.nc')
```

Comment: Thanks! I've been meaning to try out xray for a while now and this looks to be a good impetus. I appreciate your help.